# Error when creating OAuth 2.0 Service Account client ID for a Project

Tags: api, google-api

My account is the owner. It shows this error when I tried creating a Service Account client ID .

```
An internal error occurred: Error (projectId=xxxxx) INTERNAL : Failed to create new key for client: xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com, reason: Internal robots may not specify public certs"
```

Hope to hear from you.

Comment: yeah, it's happening the same for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to fix it by specifying a "product name" and "email address" on the "consent screen" settings page within "APIs and Auth". Note that a consent screen isn't relevant to what I'm working on and hadn't ever visited that page.

Comment: Make sure you have specified an email address in addition to the product name.

Comment: I have specified an email addres, anyway I did it through the old console and then everything worked fine.